# How to increase the audio length using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have the MP3 audio file `output.mp3` with `00:00:01` length.
I want to convert the audio file to `output_test.mp3` with `00:00:50` length.
The audio file should be play repeat at end of length `00:00:50`. How to do it?

```
$imgDir     = 'upload/2016/01/tmp_81332';
$ffmpeg     = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

// Convert Audio Length Path
$convAudioPath  = $imgDir."/output.mp3";
$convAudioPath_test = $imgDir."/output_test.mp3";

exec("$ffmpeg -i $convAudioPath -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:50.000 $convAudioPath_test");
```

Advise any idea!

Comment: Do you want to make the mp3 run slower, or do you want to append a (silent) audio file?

Comment: Also note that executing a program with PHP doesn't make it a programming question. What you are asking are the parameters for ffmpeg only, that makes it more suitable for [su], I'm voting to close the question as off topic.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider : I want to repeat audio file for 50 seconds.

Comment: Tried the loop parameter? http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
exec("$ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i $convAudioPath -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:50.000 $convAudioPath_test");
```

Comment: Audio file `output_test.mp3` length is 00:00:50 but the audio is not repeat at end of audio length.

Comment: Use edited command. I did not read the comments to the question.Thought you just wanted increased length.

Comment: Sorry in my mistake i did not edit my question. Is it possible to repeat audio?

Comment: Yes, see edited command.

Comment: It's not working. Means audio is not repeated at the end of length.

Comment: If you're using ffmpeg build older than [Oct 15 2015](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/dbb03b8e47f905f0f7b10c3eb5ac11f9bfc793ff), you should try `-loop 1`

Comment: After your edited command the output file `output_test.mp3` is not generated.

Comment: Run it in a shell and paste the complete console output

Comment: it's working fine.Thanks!